# Подключение вместо UI - py файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

При подключении `.py` файла, который был раньше `.ui`, возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "InsaneMacro.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sys, os, pyautogui, time, random, InsaneUi
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\PyQt\compl\InsaneUi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура
```

Погуглил, было сказано добавить в ***PATH*** пути к `PyQt5, PyQt5\...\Qt\bin`
Добавление не помогло.
Указывал это:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin
```

Подключал так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication)
import sys, os, pyautogui, time, random, InsaneUi


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = ui.UnsaneUi.Ui.MyForm()

    window.move(0, 0)
    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    window.setWindowTitle("InsaneMacro")
    ico = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
    app.setWindowIcon(ico)
```

**InsaneUi.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(212, 201)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(212, 201))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(212, 201))
        self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 31))
        self.btnStart.setObjectName("btnStart")
        self.btnSetCount = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnSetCount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 51, 31))
        self.btnSetCount.setObjectName("btnSetCount")
        self.btnSetText = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnSetText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 191, 31))
        self.btnSetText.setObjectName("btnSetText")
        self.btnReply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnReply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 191, 31))
        self.btnReply.setObjectName("btnReply")
        self.btnParty = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnParty.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 91, 31))
        self.btnParty.setObjectName("btnParty")
        self.btnGuild = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnGuild.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 91, 31))
        self.btnGuild.setObjectName("btnGuild")
        self.btnGlobal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnGlobal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 160, 91, 31))
        self.btnGlobal.setObjectName("btnGlobal")
        self.btnNormal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnNormal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 91, 31))
        self.btnNormal.setObjectName("btnNormal")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 110, 251, 21))
        self.line_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 21))
        self.line_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 21))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.btnStart.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Запускает работу бота</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnStart.setText(_translate("Form", "Запустить"))
        self.btnSetCount.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Указывает количество сообщений которых бот будет писать в игре.</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnSetCount.setText(_translate("Form", "Кол-во"))
        self.btnSetText.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Указывает текст который будет спамится</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnSetText.setText(_translate("Form", "Указать текст для спама"))
        self.btnReply.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Будет отправлять отвечать на сообщение лички заготовленным текстом</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnReply.setText(_translate("Form", "Отвечать в лс"))
        self.btnParty.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в чат пати</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnParty.setText(_translate("Form", "Пати"))
        self.btnGuild.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в чат гильдии</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnGuild.setText(_translate("Form", "Гильдия"))
        self.btnGlobal.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в глобальный чат</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnGlobal.setText(_translate("Form", "Глобал"))
        self.btnNormal.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в локальный чат</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnNormal.setText(_translate("Form", "Дефаулт"))
```

Без конвертации из `.ui` файла в `.py` - ошибок не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно что вы не публикуете модуль `InsaneUi.py`

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                             QInputDialog, QApplication)
import os
import pyautogui
import time
import random

import InsaneUi                                              # +++

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

#    ui = ui.UnsaneUi.Ui.MyForm()

    ui = InsaneUi.Ui_Form()                                   # +++
    ui.setupUi(window)                                        # +++

    window.move(0, 0)
    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    window.setWindowTitle("InsaneMacro")
    ico = QtGui.QIcon("im.png")
    app.setWindowIcon(ico)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**InsaneUi.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(212, 201)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(212, 201))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(212, 201))
        self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 31))
        self.btnStart.setObjectName("btnStart")
        self.btnSetCount = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnSetCount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 51, 31))
        self.btnSetCount.setObjectName("btnSetCount")
        self.btnSetText = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnSetText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 191, 31))
        self.btnSetText.setObjectName("btnSetText")
        self.btnReply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnReply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 191, 31))
        self.btnReply.setObjectName("btnReply")
        self.btnParty = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnParty.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 91, 31))
        self.btnParty.setObjectName("btnParty")
        self.btnGuild = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnGuild.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 91, 31))
        self.btnGuild.setObjectName("btnGuild")
        self.btnGlobal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnGlobal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 160, 91, 31))
        self.btnGlobal.setObjectName("btnGlobal")
        self.btnNormal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnNormal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 91, 31))
        self.btnNormal.setObjectName("btnNormal")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 110, 251, 21))
        self.line_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 21))
        self.line_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 21))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.btnStart.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Запускает работу бота</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnStart.setText(_translate("Form", "Запустить"))
        self.btnSetCount.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Указывает количество сообщений которых бот будет писать в игре.</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnSetCount.setText(_translate("Form", "Кол-во"))
        self.btnSetText.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Указывает текст который будет спамится</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnSetText.setText(_translate("Form", "Указать текст для спама"))
        self.btnReply.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Будет отправлять отвечать на сообщение лички заготовленным текстом</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnReply.setText(_translate("Form", "Отвечать в лс"))
        self.btnParty.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в чат пати</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnParty.setText(_translate("Form", "Пати"))
        self.btnGuild.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в чат гильдии</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnGuild.setText(_translate("Form", "Гильдия"))
        self.btnGlobal.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в глобальный чат</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnGlobal.setText(_translate("Form", "Глобал"))
        self.btnNormal.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Писать в локальный чат</p></body></html>"))
        self.btnNormal.setText(_translate("Form", "Дефаулт"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Обновил вопрос, добавив туда код InsaneUi.

Comment: @Slavatar  все работает. Я обновил пример с вашим  InsaneUi